# How to interpret returncodes from Python's subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess, runtime-error

I'm currently running a set of unittests, that actually crash. So, in order to run all of them and get a sense of what's causing the crash, I'm using Python's subprocess module in the following code - `tester.py`

```
import os
import subprocess

test_dir = './.build_release/test/'
test_files = sorted(os.listdir(test_dir)) # Gets all unittest files

with open('test_results_bad.txt','w') as f: # Save results of unittests in text file
    for curr_test in test_files:
        # Show current test
        f.write(curr_test + ' ')
        print(curr_test)

        # Run current test
        curr_proc = subprocess.run([os.path.join(test_dir, curr_test)], shell=False)

        # Indicate whether current test crashed or not
        if curr_proc.returncode == 0:
            f.write("PASSED\n")
        else:
            f.write("F A I L E D ..... ????" + str(curr_proc.returncode) + '\n')
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I encounter the crashes when attempting to build DeepLab_v2 from https://bitbucket.org/aquariusjay/deeplab-public-ver2.git

The three unittests that crash have returncodes of -6, -6 and -11. What do these mean?

I've Googled around and succeeded only in getting myself confused. I gather that the negative signs are indicative of an error, but can find no way to discern what information the values of 6 & 11 should be giving me.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Will it be able to know what to do with the test file? What type of files are the test files. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Error codes for any given program are program-specific. The convention is that 0 is success and anything else is an error, but what exactly the error is varies from program to program. You're running a bunch of testfiles, so you'd have to look at them in detail to see what they're returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those return codes are defined within the program you are running via a subprocess, they are not general OS error codes or Python codes.  Look for documentation on the code you are calling via the subprocess.  As an example, here is a batch script that returns an error code.

```
@echo off
if /I "%~1"=="TEST" (exit 5) else (exit 0)
```

If you call this using a subprocess, you will get code `0` for any argument other than `TEST`.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['test.bat', 'hello world'])
# returns:
0

subprocess.call(['test.bat', 'TEST'])
# returns:
5
```